# Disable validation in angular until the ajax request that downloads the model is finished

Tags: angularjs, validation, client-side-validation

Hello, is there a simple way to disable validation while an ajax request is downloading the model from the server?

Let's say I have this input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FieldName" name="FieldName"
  ng-model="model.thefield" required ng-maxlength="100">
```

And this model which does not pass the validation initially:

```
$scope.model = {}
```

So, the input is invalid until the request finishes:

```
$http.get('/some/url')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.model = response.data;
    });
```

Is there a way to disable validation until this request has finished. I currently set the model to a valid value initially. Example:

```
$scope.model = {
    thefield: "loading"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'disable validation'? Do you want to stop validation so that `required` and `ng-maxlength` do not work until the request is finished? Or you want to validate input field until the request is finished and after that it should not validate input?

Comment: "Do you want to stop validation so that required and ng-maxlength do not work until the request is finished?" this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change your `required` to `ng-required="yourBool"` and then write

```
$http.get('/some/url')
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.yourBool = true;
    $scope.model = response.data;
  });
```